# Add sitemap.xml inside a view

Tags: views, xml-sitemap

I already generate my xml sitemap with drupal module "sitemap" now i wanted to show that sitemap inside a view.

It is possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, or at least not, with XML Sitemap & Views module. There is no Views integration with the XML Sitemap module. Given how both these modules work (a view being defined by base table & XML sitemap trying to generate a list of all indexable site paths), I think you'd be better off looking for another solution to embed all your site paths into the site.

Comment: you're completly rigth, im going to build a custom module, thanks for your answer